# pyQGIS - set grid annotation direction 'Vertical Descending'

Tags: pyqgis

I am using pyqgis to create map automatically. However I encounter a problem when I want to set the grid annotation direction to 'Vertical Descending'.
The command I use is the following:

```
composerMap.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMap.OutsideMapFrame, \
                                                  QgsComposerMap.Top)

composerMap.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMap.VerticalDescending, \
                                               QgsComposerMap.Top)
```

However, I get the following attribute error:

> QgsComposerMap has no attributes VerticalDescending

After looking online, I found that this method is deprecated (https://qgis.org/api/deprecated.html) and that I should use grid() or grids() instead. When I look at qgscomposermapgrid.h source code (https://qgis.org/api/qgscomposermapgrid_8h_source.html#l00211) I see that there is an attribute 'VerticalDescending' (line 215) but I cannot find any example on how to use this method.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out:

```
composerMap.setGridAnnotationPosition(QgsComposerMapGrid.OutsideMapFrame, \
                                      QgsComposerMapGrid.Top)

composerMap.setGridAnnotationDirection(QgsComposerMapGrid.VerticalDescending, \
                                       QgsComposerMapGrid.Top)
```

Now, these constants ('OutsideMapFrame', 'VerticalDescending', 'Top') are all in **QgsComposerMapGrid** class; not in **QgsComposerMap** class.

I corroborated that with my 'Get Pattern' plugin:

[image]

and at the Python Console:

```
>>>QgsComposerMapGrid.OutsideMapFrame
1
>>>QgsComposerMapGrid.Top
3
>>>QgsComposerMapGrid.VerticalDescending
2
```